# i have i minecraft survival world but i want to invite worldwide friends to my world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can anybody help me with this? I have some friends that are NOT local so a LAN world would not be able  to reach them, so how would i do this i don't want to make a world wide server that anybody can join. I live in the northern part of the united state's, one of my friends lives in California and one lives in Australia.
So how would i go about making a server that BOTH of them would be able to reach?!

Comment: Suggestion: Go search up hosting lan over hamachi

Answer (score 1):

You could make a whitelisted server.

You set up a server normally, but set white-list=true in your server.properties, then add only your friends' (and your own) usernames to the whitelist.

Only share the IP directly with your friends, don't post it on a website - people who aren't on the whitelist can't join anyway, but there's no reason to even let them try.

Downside:  Every time a new player wants to join, you'll have to manually add them to the list of allowed players.

Upside:  That means no one can ever join the server without your explicit permission.

Comment: I think they need help more with the setting up a server part that the making it whitelisted part...

Comment: The "...i don't want to make a world wide server that anybody can join." part of their question leads me to believe they know how to do that.  If they do that, then turn on the whitelist, it does what they want.  If they need more help, I'm 99% sure "how do I make a server?" is already on Arqade somewhere...